# CSS: -ms-clear not available in IE11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

P.s: Pls dont mark duplicate without reading the entire question

Dear All,

I want to remove the cross[X] icon for the input field.

I very well know it can be done using CSS

```
.input::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

But somehow this property is not available in IE11, and even if i forcefully use this property IE is not identifying it. Is there any alternative property available for it. I tried searching but i didnt find any.

Comment: Maybe you are selecting wrong element? Seems to be working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/ddqsay9m/1/

Comment: the ".input" is that a generally solution for all input fields in IE browsers or is it a css class?

If it is supposed to be a general css property for the input field, then remove the "."

Comment: @McBoman : u were correct

Comment: @Shirish Remember to mark answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed it was a

```
.
```

infront of

```
.input::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

That caused the error.